# Different Animation Through CSS

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have few elements in my HTML page which are only images and tooltip. I wanted them to animate randomly based on the animation I have done on the CSS part.

Currently all the elements will animate together when the page is loaded, I do no want this.

I am thinking of calling the CSS class from jQuery one by one, but looking at the number of elements and since it is just a basic translation animation, is there any better way to do this?

Here are the elements:

```
<div class="twitter-animate">
  <div id="twitter-wrap"><a href="#" id="twitter"><img src="img/link-twitter.png"></a></div>
    <div id="twitter-tooltip"><span>Tweet!</span></div>
</div>


    <div id="youtube-wrap"><a href="#" id="youtube"><img src="img/link-youtube.png"></a></div>
    <div id="youtube-tooltip"><span>YouTube</span></div>

    <div id="facebook-wrap"><a href="#" id="facebook"><img src="img/link-fb.png"></a></div>
    <div id="facebook-tooltip"><span>Facebook</span></div>

    <div id="newspaper-wrap"><a href="#" id="newspaper"><img src="img/link-newspaper.png"></a></div>
    <div id="newspaper-tooltip"><span>Newspaper</span></div>

    <div id="www-wrap"><a href="#" id="www"><img src="img/link-www.png"></a></div>
    <div id="www-tooltip"><span>Put your URL!</span></div>

    <div id="email-wrap"><a href="#" id="email"><img src="img/link-email.png"></a></div>
    <div id="email-tooltip"><span>Mail me!</span></div>
```

Comment: can you explain how your animation is done now?

Comment: Can you provide a jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ showing what you are currently doing>

Comment: The image is very complicated to be uploaded.

The basic idea is like this, it is a robot with certain parts of the body being animated (say only hands, head or the canon arms), while the rest are being set as the background. 

So I wanted each part to animate after each another finish their animation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the sake of simplicity I'm going to assume you want your elements to to be translated from left to right. The tooltips are also irrelevant, so I'll remove them.

The first thing you need to do is add a common class to all your elements. Here I added `share` as a class:

```
<div id="twitter-wrap" class="share"><a href="#" id="twitter">Twitter</a></div>
<div id="youtube-wrap" class="share"><a href="#" id="youtube">YouTube</a></div>
<div id="facebook-wrap" class="share"><a href="#" id="facebook">Facebook</a></div>
<div id="newspaper-wrap" class="share"><a href="#" id="newspaper">Newspaper</a></div>
<div id="www-wrap" class="share"><a href="#" id="www">WWW</a></div>
<div id="email-wrap" class="share"><a href="#" id="email">Email</a></div>
```

Then your CSS should look something like this...

```
.share {
  width: 100px;
  background-color: #333;
  padding: 3px  0 3px 10px;
  margin-bottom: 3px;
  -webkit-transform: translate(-100px, 0);
  -moz-transform: translate(-100px, 0); 
  -o-transform: translate(-100px, 0);  
  -ms-transform: translate(-100px, 0); 
   transform: translate(-100px, 0); 
  -webkit-transition: all 500ms ease;
  -moz-transition: all 500ms ease; 
  -o-transition: all 500ms ease;  
  -ms-transition: all 500ms ease;
   transition: all 500ms ease;    
}

.share.animate {
  -webkit-transform: translate(0, 0);
  -moz-transform: translate(0, 0); 
  -o-transform: translate(0, 0);  
  -ms-transform: translate(0, 0); 
   transform: translate(0, 0); 
}
```

​Then you need a little bit of javascript to fire off the first animation, and then listen when each trasition ends to fire off the next one...

```
//after document ready
$(".share").first().addClass("animate")

$(".share").bind("webkitTransitionEnd oTransitionEnd msTransitionEnd transitionend", function(e){
  $(e.target).next('.share').addClass("animate");
})
```

You can find it all put together here: http://jsfiddle.net/HYAWj/

Comment: Thank you for your help, I get a better understanding on how to do it now.

But for my case, there is a slight problem, coz the animations aren't suppose to go to the same direction, some of them appears from right, while others from left.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want them all to animate together, but rather after certain time intervals then use:

```
setTimeout(function() {
    //Put in animation here
}, 2500);
```

where 2500 is the time in ms for the delay before the code within the setTimeout is run.

Comment: Sorry, but the animation is done within a CSS, how do I apply this method? Since every ID have their own styling and animation.

Comment: If you must use CSS to do your animation then add a class to your element and put the animation in that class.

$("element").addClass("myClass");
Add this line within the setTimeout

Comment: Okay, for the current state of development, I have different styling for **#twitter** , **#twitter-wrap** , **twitter-tooltip** and **twitter-tooltip span**

If I add the class like above, how to apply this concept?